# Обработка и создание CSV файла

Tags: python, дата, csv, датасет

Есть определенный датасет (CSV файл) содержащий инфу о фильмах:

```
Title,Rating,Votes,Gross,Genre,Metascore,Certificate,Director,Year,Description,Runtime
Sen to Chihiro no kamikakushi,8.6,"747,148",$10.06M," Adventure, Family",96,U,Hayao Miyazaki,2001,"[""\nDuring her family's move to the suburbs, a sullen 10-year-old girl wanders into a world ruled by gods, witches, and spirits, and where humans are changed into beasts.""]",125 min
The Lion King,8.5,"1,041,158",$422.78M," Adventure, Drama",88,U,Roger Allers,1994,"['\nLion prince Simba and his father are targeted by his bitter uncle, who wants to ascend the throne himself.']",88 min
```

Нужно из первого CSV файла сделать новый, используя из датасета только столбцы `Director` `Rating` `Votes`

Соответственно вопрос:
Как записать новую таблицу в файл используя только данные нужных мне столбцов.
Дошел только до переписки всех данных в новый CSV (пытался сначала записать столбец директоров):

```py
import csv
directors = list()
fieldnames = None
with open("TopAnimated.csv", mode = "r") as table:
    t = csv.DictReader(table)
    fieldnames = t.fieldnames
    for row in t:
      if row["Director"]:
        directors.append(row)

with open("sorted_table.csv", mode = "w") as sorted_table:
  st = csv.DictWriter(sorted_table, fieldnames)
  st.writeheader()
  st.writerows(directors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите `Pandas` и не мучайтесь:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TopAnimated.csv")
df = df[['Director', 'Rating', 'Votes']]
df.to_csv("sorted_table.csv")
```

Там могут быть какие-то тонкости настройки чтения и записи, но в целом должно быть вот так просто.